# What does 0600 mean in a function? Is it same as \200?

Tags: c, ascii, octal

I'm trying to write the memccpy() function myself. I'll call is ft_memccpy().
I found test main functions online and there are two test functions that confuse me.
The first test function works fine with my ft_memccpy() but the second test function doesn't.
And I don't get it because the only difference between test1 and test2 is that \200 is changed to 0600.

Here's the ft_memccpy I made:

```
void    *ft_memccpy(void *dest, const void *src, int c, size_t n)
{
    char    *dptr;
    char    *sptr;

    dptr = (char *)dest;
    sptr = (char *)src;
    while (n && *dptr && *sptr)
    {
        *dptr = *sptr;
        if (*sptr == c)
        {
            return (++dptr);
        }
        dptr++;
        sptr++;
        n--;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Here's the first test function(test1) where my function works fine:

```
#include "ft_memccpy.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char dest[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
    char dest2[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
    char src[] = "string with\200inside !";
    int n = 21;

    memccpy(dest2, src, '\200', n);
    printf("%s\n", dest2);
    ft_memccpy(dest, src, '\200', n);
    printf("%s\n", dest);
}
```

and here's the second test (test2) where my function doesn't work:

```
#include "ft_memccpy.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char dest[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
    char dest2[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
    char src[] = "string with\200inside !";
    int n = 21;

    memccpy(dest2, src, 0600, n);
    printf("%s\n", dest2);
    ft_memccpy(dest, src, 0600, n);
    printf("%s\n", dest);
}
```

I figured out 0600 is octal and is supposed to be 384 in decimal,
but 384 is not in the ascii code right?
The only stuff I get about 0600 is "chmod 0600" which doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Correct. 0600 is octal 600.

Comment: Are you sure it's \200 and not '\200'?

Comment: Digits with leading zeros are [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).  That is `0600` is `6*8² + 0*8 + 0*8⁰` == `384`.

Comment: And since you really can't have a `char` value above `255` (or `127` signed), searching for a byte who's decimal value is 384 is going to be problematic.

Comment: BTW, `#include` is not normally used for `.c` files. You should include the `.h` file that declares `ft_memccpy`, and link with `ft_memccpy.o`.

Comment: @selbie: `memccpy` converts its third argument to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @selbie: There do exist machines that have `char` values larger than 8 bit, although they are rare.

Comment: Sorry! I changed \200 to '\200'!

Comment: 0600 is 110-000-000 in binary.  9 bits don't usually fit in an 8-bit char, so you're left with 10-000-000.  That's 0200.  That didn't change because of your function, the 9th bit got hacked-off by the compiler.  No diagnostic required, ideally it warns you anyway.

Comment: BTW, good use of `while (n && *dptr && *sptr)` and not `while (*dptr && *sptr && n)`

Comment: @EricPostpischil - sure, but the OP's implementation of `ft_memccpy` doesnt't do that. And further, converting `384` back to a char is going to lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @Bathsheba - you are correct. I've seen some in museums before.

Comment: @selbie: Converting the argument to `unsigned char` is part of the specification of `memccpy`. If `ft_memccpy` does not do that, it is defective.

Comment: @HansPassant This is brilliant! I would have never thought of this. Thank you so much

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh I didn't do that on purpose! Why is that better?

Comment: @HansPassant However, I just changed 0600 to 0200 and it still didn't work
Shouldn't 0200 work because that is same as '\200'?

Comment: "Why is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454923/what-does-0600-mean-in-a-function-is-it-same-as-200?noredirect=1#comment106951136_60454923) better?"  --> could should not access referenced data when `n==0` as it might be out of bounds of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Convert compare to use `unsigned char`.

```
void *ft_memccpy(void *dest, const void *src, int c, size_t n) {
    unsigned char *dptr = (unsigned char *) dest;
    // better style to not cast away const-ness
    const unsigned char *sptr = (const unsigned char *) src;

    while (n && *dptr && *sptr) {
        *dptr = *sptr;
        if (*sptr == (unsigned char)c) {
            return (++dptr);
        }
        dptr++;
        sptr++;
        n--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

String-like functions tend to only use the character value even when the argument is `int`.  Thus `c` as 0600 (384<sub>10</sub>) should only use 0200 (128<sub>10</sub>) for the compare for the common 8-bit `unsigned char`.

Performing a `unsigned char` rather than `char` or `signed char` is important too.  In this case, it avoid *implementation defined behavior* converting `int`to *signed* `char` and  with rare non-2's complement to avoid traps and not compare +0 as -0.

Answer (score 1):

The `sptr` is a array of `char`, so you need to convert the `c` from an `int` to a `char` so that the equals make sense:

```
    ...
    if (*sptr == (char) c)
    ...
```